# Method using EventWaitHandles returning earlier than expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I've created a simple method which is supposed to take a list of, say, 100 items, and process them asynchronously (up to `MAX_CONCURRENT` elements at a time), and return only once all elements have been processed:

```
/// <summary>Generic method to perform an action or set of actions
///          in parallel on each item in a collection of items, returning
///          only when all actions have been completed.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The element type</typeparam>
/// <param name="elements">A collection of elements, each of which to
///                        perform the action on.</param>
/// <param name="action">The action to perform on each element. The
///                      action should of course be thread safe.</param>
/// <param name="MAX_CONCURRENT">The maximum number of concurrent actions.</param>
```

---

```
public static void PerformActionsInParallel<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T> action)
{
    // Semaphore limiting the number of parallel requests
    Semaphore limit = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT, MAX_CONCURRENT);
    // Count of the number of remaining threads to be completed
    int remaining = 0;
    // Signal to notify the main thread when a worker is done
    AutoResetEvent onComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    foreach (T element in elements)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref remaining);
        limit.WaitOne();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                action(element);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error performing concurrent action: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref remaining);
                limit.Release();
                onComplete.Set();
            }
        }).Start();
    }
    // Wait for all requests to complete
    while (remaining > 0)
        onComplete.WaitOne(10); // Slightly better than Thread.Sleep(10)
}
```

---

```
    /* We include a timeout on the `WaitOne()` before checking `remaining` again
        * to protect against the rare case where the last outstanding thread
        * decrements 'remaining' and then signals completion *between* the main thread
        * checking 'remaining' and waiting for the next completion signal, which would
        * otherwise result in the main thread missing the last signal and locking forever. */
```

Most of the time, this code behaves exactly as expected, but in rare occasions, I discover that the method returns (i.e. breaks out of that final while loop) before every element in the list is finished processing. It always seems to happen when there's only a few elements left - e.g. I'll have processed 97 elements, and then the method returns, and then elements 98-100 complete.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong that's maybe resulting in the `remaining` count hitting 0 before all elements have actually been processed?

Comment: It is formally wrong, the *int* is not used in a thread-safe way.  Also quite possible that the while-loop never completes since the *int* is not declared volatile.  Use the CountDownEvent class instead, get rid of onComplete.

Comment: Note that while I agree with Hans' observations and suggestion, you _could_ fix the volatile issue by using `Volatile.Read()` to access the value at the end (that's where the lack of thread safety is a problem). I still wouldn't recommend doing it that way; polling a variable like that is wasteful and unnecessary. Use an appropriate synchronization mechanism that works. Frankly, it's not clear to me why you poll the variable anyway; just have the last thread (i.e. the one that decrements `remaining` to 0) set the event, and wait on the event. Or use `CountdownEvent`, which is made for this

Comment: Also note that you seem to be reinventing `Parallel.ForEach()`. If this is an academic exercise, fine...but if not, consider using the built-in features instead of writing them again. :)

Comment: @HansPassant What isn't thread safe? I use `Interlocked.Decrement` and I thought reading a 32 bit int was atomic?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I tried that but I can't have just the thread that decrements remaining to 0 because if the for loop hasn't executed its second loop yet, `remaining` will still be set to 1 when it is decremented back to 0 and `complete` will be set too early,

Comment: @PeterDuniho Any .NET4 substitutes for `Volatile.Read()` that you know of?

Comment: _"What isn't thread safe"_ -- interlocked instructions are not necessarily volatile operations (i.e. documentation doesn't promise that), so reading `remaining` in the main thread may or may not show the actual most recent value for the variable (though, on x86 it almost certainly will, better safe than sorry). I will note that I have found conflicting information on the web; some articles claim that `Interlocked` implies a full memory fence around each operation, so volatile access is implied. Others say that no fence is implied; only atomicity. I opt for the more conservative assumption.

Comment: _"`complete` will be set too early"_ -- this should be addressable by having the main thread count itself (i.e. increment before entering the loop), and then having it only wait (or have it set the wait handle) if when it decrements on exiting the loop, the value went to 0. _".NET4 substitutes for `Volatile.Read()`"_ -- See [Thread.VolatileRead()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatileread(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks, I gave PLINQ a shot but it only ever uses as many threads as I have logical processors, which is sub-optimal in my use case - because the threads aren't CPU-intensive, they're Server-bound, and I get the best speed up by 'queuing up' many requests on the server rather than just as many requests as I have cores. If PLINQ let you manually set the number of threads to use it would be an elegant solution. VolatileRead may have worked, but CountdownEvent turned out to make everything much simpler :)

Comment: If you are dealing with I/O with a remote server, you probably don't want to be using threads at all. More than likely, the API you're using to interact with the server includes asynchronous methods. Frankly, even in the example you provided, it would be better to just use `Task.Run()` so you can `await` their completion (i.e. `Task.WhenAll()`). But even better would be to not tie up a thread at all, something the usual .NET I/O classes all support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified solution that makes use of a `CountdownEvent` signal to avoid the use of the `remaining` integer and avoid the busy waiting involved in polling it with the unreliable `AutoResetEvent onComplete`:

```
public static void PerformActionsInParallel<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T> action)
{
    int threads = MaxConcurrent ?? DefaultMaxConcurrentRequests;
    // Ensure elements is only enumerated once.
    elements = elements as T[] ?? elements.ToArray();
    // Semaphore limiting the number of parallel requests
    Semaphore limit = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT, MAX_CONCURRENT);
    // Count of the number of remaining threads to be completed
    CountdownEvent remaining = new CountdownEvent(elements.Count());

    foreach (T element in elements)
    {
        limit.WaitOne();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                action(element);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error performing concurrent action: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                remaining.Signal();
                limit.Release();
            }
        }).Start();
    }
    // Wait for all requests to complete
    remaining.Wait();
}
```

Testing underway to see if it solves the issue.